# Codeigniter model with multiple update conditions using manual where statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I have this code in model that returns data

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');

$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss'";

$this->db->where($where);

$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

return $query->result();
```

I am using a manual `where` and i wanted to know whether the concept of manual where in updates and possibly in deletes is allowed.

This code updates a table based on a single `where` condition

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
             );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Is doing this allowed in codeigniter

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
             );

$where = "id=$id, name='Joe' AND status='boss'";

$this->db->where($where);

$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per document in CodeIgniter [Where](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where_in#looking-for-specific-data), you have to mention here with `OR` or `AND` `"id=$id, name='Joe'`.

```
$where = "id=$id AND/OR name='Joe' AND status='boss'";
                  ^^^^
                Chose one
```

[image]

---

Or use array

[image]

Comment: Oh cool. I also found that you must have set to `$data = array(
               'title' => 'Sail',
               'rental_rate' => '10'
             );

$where = "title='VAN HELSING' AND rating='R'";

$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->update('film', $data);`

Comment: happy to help :)